# how to reverse proxy via nginx a specific url?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a server running at `http://localhost:8080` i want a specific url of this server to be proxied by nginx.

For example, i only want `http://localhost:8080/test/(.*)` to be reverse proxied to `http://localhost/test/(.*)`.

I'm proxing another server to `http://localhost/`.

Comment: How to achieve this via Envoy Reverse Proxy?
Like say we want to redirect requests coming from 
http://www.example.com:3443/node-exporter/metrics to http://localhost:9001/metrics.
How does one go about this?

Comment: Hi! Can someone answer this related question as well? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74307209/how-to-use-envoy-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-a-specific-url-on-localhost

Answer (score 2):

What about just a simple `location` block?

```
server {
    # ... other stuff

    location /test/ {
        try_files $uri @testproxy;
    }

    location @testproxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # all your params
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made it somehow this way and it worked. Thanks for your comment anyway. :)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # ... other stuff

    upstream backend1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location /test/ {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://backend1/test/;
    }
}
```