# NGINX Ignore HTTPS for single page

Tags: ssl, nginx, nginx-location

I have a video portal system that plays live streams. The issue is that the live streams are created on the fly via docker, so I can't secure them easily (HTTPS). I need a way to tell NGINX not to secure (HTTP) a single page at `{my_domain}/portal/{url_variable}` but make sure the rest of the site will be HTTPS. Here is my current config:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/app.domain.com/before/*;

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name app.domain.com;
root /home/forge/app.domain.com/public;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/app.domain.com/111111/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/app.domain.com/111111/server.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'stuff';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

I have attempted to add another server that listens to port 80 and use location for only for the portal URL, but the entire site then does not render.

Comment: *"... the live streams are created on the fly via docker, so I can't secure them easily..."* - I don't understand this problem. For the ability to use HTTPS it should not matter at all if the video stream is generated dynamically or is a static file. But in any case if you want to use HTTP for parts of your site then you need to configure port 80 adequately, since this is the port used for HTTP. Having only port 443 configured as you do will only allow access by HTTPS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich How would I only allow port 80 on a single page `/portal/{URLVar}`?

Comment: Just to explain. The live streams are served via HTTP and the site is HTTPS. Like you said, this won't work since you can't serve HTTP assets in HTTPS. My solution is to not serve this single page as HTTPS but as HTTP. My question is, how do I do this with NGINX?

Comment: If the live stream is already served by HTTP as you say then this means that there must be another server doing this, which is independent from your server. So you don't need to do anything on your server but the URL for the live stream should just point to the server providing the live stream. If you don't want to expose the server to the public you might use your [nginx as a reverse proxy for this specific internal URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262663/how-to-reverse-proxy-via-nginx-a-specific-url) and this way the internal HTTP URL can be accessed by HTTPS from outside.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing or I'm just not following you. I have a portal here: `https://app.domain.com/portal/stream_name` and I need to get my video player to serve the stream which is `http://206.189.200.80:5732/hls/stream_name.m3u8`
Currently it won't because I cannot serve http on an https page.

Comment: The stream has a URL already. Either you let the client access this URL directly in which case no changes to your nginx are needed. Or you make your nginx proxy this URL, i.e. [proxy_pass](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) one external visible URL (nginx location) to the internal URL. And with this you can make the internal URL be available using HTTPS to the internet, even if the internal URL was HTTP only.

Comment: I see where you are going with this. Do you mind making this an answer with an example?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich this worked perfectly BTW

Comment: There are enough posts on how to use nginx as proxy for internal servers. No need to make another answer. Glad it worked for you.